# Drawing many UIBezierPaths in a view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, quartz-graphics, uibezierpath

I am drawing several `UIBezierPath`s on a view based on finger movements.

Every time a cycle of touches -- Began/Moved/Ended -- completes, I store the points and create a `UIBezierPath` that is stored in an array called `bezierArray`. I have another array called `bezierArrayColors` that stores the colors of each path.

The problem is this. The class uses `drawRect`. As far as I can see, every time `drawRect` runs, it has to draw all the paths that were ever created and the app is now slow.

This is my `drawRect` now. I know it is pretty lame, but I am not seeing how this can be done.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
   for (int i=0; i<[self.bezierArray count]; i++) {
        UIBezierPath *aPath = (UIBezierPath*)[self.bezierArray objectAtIndex:i];
        UIColor *aColor = (UIColor*)[self.bezierArrayColor objectAtIndex:i];
    [aPath setLineWidth:LINE_WIDTH];

    [aColor setStroke];
    [aPath stroke];
    }
}
```

Is there a way to stroke a `UIBezierPath` with different colors or perhaps widths using subpaths? I mean, to change color, width and other properties of a subpath? That would allow me to use one `UIBezierPath` with several different subpaths. I wish one bezier could be drawn and left there without needing to be redrawn every time. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that you pay attention to the rect that's passed into -drawRect:. If your code takes the easy way out and redraws the entire view every time -drawRect: is called, you may be doing far more drawing than necessary at least some of the time.

Comment: Hi @Celeb . plz check my method - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{ [brushPattern setStroke]; [myPath strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeHardLight alpha:0.5];} i m working with live camera . i can draw successullly on live camera .. i have set few button to change the color of pain brush . when i pick any from this and start again paing than previous context paint color also change.. so can u plz suggest me how can we resolve that ? and is there any functionality to erase this paint ?

Answer (score 2):

Draw each bezier path in a separate subview. That way each bezier only has to be redrawn when it itself has changed.

Comment: no other way to do that? this will generate on trillion subviews!!! and if I want to support an eraser? this will not work.

Comment: Why do you have a trillion bezier paths? Are you creating a path for every single touchesMoved? Also, if you want to add an eraser, drawing into a bitmap is almost certainly a better idea than storing paths and drawing them in drawRect.

Comment: every toucheBegan creates a new path that finishes on touchesended and is stored. I had it working using bitmaps but it was pretty slow, so I am trying to do it with paths.

Comment: Depending on what kind of drawing app you're doing, subviews might actually work. Views are fairly cheap. About bitmaps, I don't have any hard numbers, but rendering vectors is almost certainly going to be slower than just copying an existing bitmap into the drawing context.

Comment: +1 Don't know why this was downvoted... it's a reasonable enough suggestion and certainly not incorrect, misleading, or otherwise inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and plan to use a subview to hold all the "completed" paths and another subview to hold just the path "in progress". This way I don't have to draw all the completed paths as I get new touchesmoved events for the "in progress" path(s). Once the path is complete, I move it to the completed array, redraw the completed subview, and await the next touch. This avoids the "trillions of subviews" problem, and also avoids redrawing the whole array of paths while actually trying to respond to touches, which are very sensitive to delays. Once I get this going, I'll try to remember to return here with some code.